# How to Fill in Empty Matrix in R with Loop

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I have a blank matrix called Trial that is 5000 X 5000, but i'll put a small snippet.

```
     a  b  c  d  e  f 
 a  

 b  

 c  

 d  

 e  

 f
```

and I want to fill the Matrix, with a Data Table I have.

```
Name Value
-----------
Cat   A 
Cat   B
Cat   E
Dog   D
Dog   C
Dog   F
```

So basically in the end, I want the matrix to be filled like this:

```
     a  b  c  d  e  f 
 a   1  1  0  0  1  0

 b   1  1  0  0  1  0

 c   0  0  1  1  0  1

 d   0  0  1  1  0  1

 e   1  1  0  0  1  0

 f   0  0  1  1  0  1
```

So all the values relating to the Name will be 1, and if they don't relate they will be 0. For example, A and F don't relate because they are different names (cat and dog), thus they will get a 0.

Comment: How is this _not_ a duplicate of your previous question?

Comment: The data is too large for me to use contrast; contrast only applies to factors

Comment: And, I am  trying to fill this with a loop, where in the last question I was not..

Comment: You have another answer on the previous question that does not use contrast; anything can be turned into a factor with `factor`;you should probably _not_ use a loop.

Comment: Yes. I got that, but his example did not work either... So I am trying to figure out how to fill the Matrix using a loop.. Why should I not try and use a loop?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way with loops

```
dd <- read.table(header = TRUE, text="Name Value
Cat   A 
Cat   B
Cat   E
Dog   D
Dog   C
Dog   F")

o <- order(dd$Value)
sapply(1:nrow(dd), function(x) dd$Name %in% dd[x, 'Name'] + 0L)[o, o]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1    1    0    0    1    0
# [2,]    1    1    0    0    1    0
# [3,]    0    0    1    1    0    1
# [4,]    0    0    1    1    0    1
# [5,]    1    1    0    0    1    0
# [6,]    0    0    1    1    0    1
```

or with an explicit `for` loop

```
mm <- matrix(nrow = nrow(dd), ncol = nrow(dd))
for (ii in 1:nrow(mm))
  mm[ii, ] <- dd$Name %in% dd[ii, 'Name'] + 0L
mm[o, o]
```

For 5000 x 5000, takes less than 2 seconds on my crummy laptop

```
dd <- data.frame(Name = sample(LETTERS, 5000, replace = TRUE), Value = 1:5000)
o <- order(dd$Value)

system.time({
  oo <- sapply(1:nrow(dd), function(x) dd$Name %in% dd[x, 'Name'] + 0L)[o, o]
})


#  user  system elapsed 
# 1.680   0.188   1.874 

system.time({
  mm <- matrix(nrow = nrow(dd), ncol = nrow(dd))
  for (ii in 1:nrow(mm))
    mm[ii, ] <- dd$Name %in% dd[ii, 'Name'] + 0L
  mm[o, o]
})

#  user  system elapsed 
# 1.918   0.152   2.073
```

Comment: Now consider `system.time({contrasts(dd$Name,contrasts=FALSE)[dd$Name,dd$Name]->oo2})`...as in the duplicate.

Comment: Wow! I'm surprised the for loop was that fast.  Good work @rawr.

Comment: @A.Webb excellent! and how did you spent your extra 1.5 seconds!

Comment: I spent it trying to close a duplicate question!